# Lists of Start and End Columns of all matches in a line

Tags: regex, list, vim, match, lines

I'm trying to create a list of start columns and a list of end columns of all matches in a line.

This is what I've done:

**line1**:

```
test is PASSED as its the list "that" is [passed] as
```

search: `\<[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]\+\>`
(find all words)

**Commands**:

```
let MatchesStart = [] | 1s/\<[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]\+\>/\=add(MatchesStart,match(getline(1),submatch(0)))/gn
let MatchesEnd = []   | 1s/\<[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]\+\>/\=add(MatchesEnd,matchend(getline(1),submatch(0)))/gn
```

**Results**:

MatchesStart = [0, 5, 8, 9, 18, 22, 26, 32, 5, 8, 9]
MatchesEnd   = [4, 7, 14, 11, 21, 25, 30, 36, 7, 14, 11]

The problem is that the matches aren't unique. The last word 'as' in the line is found in 'Passed', the last word 'is' is not found because it is detected as the 2nd word in the line, and so on.

**Expected Output**:

MatchesStart = [0, 5, 8, 15, 18, 22, 26, 32, 38, 42, 50]
MatchesEnd   = [4, 7, 14, 17, 21, 25, 30, 36, 40, 48, 52]

Please see the difference of entry 4, 9, 10 and 11.

How can I create an unique list of numbers of matches (from the start to the end of the line)?

**Update**:

Please do a search of `\s\zs\p\w\+`

To find the start and endcolumn of a match I tried `match/matchend`

match = '31'
matchend = '-1'

Searchpos gives the correct startcolumn (32) but it doesn't give an endcolumn.
You cannot use matchend to find the endcolumn because the start value is wrong a cause of the '\s' before '\zs'

Comment: It is not completely obvious to me what output you expect. Beginning and end of each word? What are you aiming at eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `searchpos()` function to search your pattern, wrap it in a loop (while e.g.)  if the 2nd element in the returned list is 0, you've done your search on that line.

`:h searchpos(` to read the details.

Comment: Doesn't searchpos() only search the start position?

Comment: @Remonn what do you want to search depends on the pattern. you can search for the `\>` then -1.

Comment: @Remonn I keep my answer and comment. Again, what do you want to match is fully depended on the pattern, the regex. If you gave the regex to match `...\>`,  the returned value -1 from searchpos() would be the number you want.

Comment: I would like to find a way to insert all start cols and end cols of matches in a line, whatever search I do.

Comment: Found it searchpos('','e') :)

Comment: @Remonn great! I hope you could finish your script/plugin soon!

Comment: Kent, still found a problem. Searchpos doesn't stop at end of line. It searches the entire file. I need only the matches in a line. There is no way to indicate a start and stopline.

Comment: Yes, still no way to add startline.

Comment: @Remonn startline is current line. searchpos() starts from your current cursor position. if it somehow cannot help you, wait for someone else's answer.

Comment: Kent, searchpos() does not count from column 1, but as you've said from current cursor position. That means that you'll never pick up a match from column 1 at the current line (the search starts after column 1). There are also problems with single character matches p.e. 'a' searchpos(@/) goes to 'a', searchpos(@/, 'e') goes to end of next match.  :-(

Comment: No, not a good idea searchpos. Searchpos() doesn't recognize characters as èéìàá etc. it count a double column for them (because they are multi-bytes?). Waiting for a better solution (other answers) but i believe they will not come ;)

Comment: found the solution with searchpos(): scan forwards and backwards on the same line using match(). Stopline=currentline. Remove doubles. Even matches at the start and end of line are found. Same for matchend().